# Creating a twilio auto dialler for outbound calls

Tags: twilio

We have developed a custom phone system for our call centre using twilio. We now want to expand on this and get our call centre operators more productive by creating an autodialler. The way we want it to work is that we will have a list of numbers, we then want to dial the numbers and only route the call through for our operators to handle if it is a successful call whereby the consumer has answered the call. If not the call will not get routed to the operator. Just wondering if there are any twilio evangelists out there that have any advice on how to implement this?

Comment: Just to add - we have looked at twilio task router as a potential solution but costs wise it isn't feasible for our company at this time.

Comment: Hey Danielle, what have you tried so far? I don't know the system that you've created, so it's hard to give advice on how to implement.